# ¿Cómo insertar cuadro de dialogo (alert) para que de acuerdo a mi confirmación ejecute el redireccionamiento?

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

El siguiente código me trae resultados de mi base de datos y me muestra un pequeño botón azul font, el cual ejecuto para cerrar un ticket que esté generado. Intenté agregarle un `confirm` con Javascript, agregando el `onclick` en la línea que redirige a mi otro script, pero me sigue ejecutando el código sin mi confirmación.

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo para que sólo responda al recibir mi confirmación?

```
    <tbody>   
          <?php
            //busqueda y muestra de los elementos de la base de datos
            while ($resultado   = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $fecha = array();
                $fecha = explode("-" ,$resultado['fecha']);
                $fecha[0] = $fecha[0]%1000;
                $resultado['estado'] == '0' ? $estado = 'Abierta': $estado = 'Cerrada';
                $resultado['estado'] == '0' ? $icono = 'fa fa-folder': $icono = 'fa fa-check';
                $resultado['estado'] == '0' ? $title = 'Cerrar': $title = 'Abrir';
                $resultado['estado'] == '0' ? $enlace = "<a title=\"".$title."\" href=\"scripts/scriptCloseSuggestion.php?id=".$resultado['id_sugerencia']."\"><i class=\"".$icono."\"></a>": $enlace = "<i class=\"".$icono."\">";

//elementos en la tabla html
                echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$resultado['nombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</td>
                  <td>".$estado."</td>
                  <td>

<button class=\"waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger\" href=\"#".$resultado['id_sugerencia']."\">Ver</button></td>
                  <td>".$enlace."</td>
                </tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
```

En mi código tengo el `.$enlace` como una variable. Cuando se muestra en el navegador, se muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
<a title="Cerrar" href="scripts/scriptCloseSuggestion.php?id=1"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></a>
```

Comment: Porque no usas bootstrap modal?? El problema de los alerts es que hasta los navegadores lo ven molestos y en algunas ocaciones te muestra algo como desea dejar de ver mensajes emergentes . Si un usuario te marca eso no podrás hacer nada

Comment: el sweet alert serviria en esos caso creo, es un alert pero mejor , ademas tiene compatibilidad con bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas agregar una confirmación con sweetalert2 después que el botón sea presionado, puedes hacer algo así (ejemplo basado en la documentación). En este ejemplo estoy utilizando la versión basada en promises de SweetAlert.

```js
function confirmar(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  swal({
    title: 'Ir a Google',
    text: "¿Estás seguro?",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sí, vamos'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      let linkElement = e.target
      while (!linkElement.href) {
        linkElement = linkElement.parentElement
      }     
      window.location.href = linkElement.href
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.15.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="confirmar(event)">Ir a enlace</a>
```

Comment: me estoy reconectando desde hace mucho tiempo, pude solucionar los problemas que tenia antes con lo de la imagen . es un juego , lo subire mañana a la web para mostrarselos.

Comment: Pero amigos, al intentarlo asi dejo de tomar un parametro php que necesito.

Comment: cuando hago el sweet alert funciona pero no me toma el valor que necesito retornar .
lo que le agregue mientras es un onclick=\"return confirm('Estas seguro?');\" a todos mis elementos mientras improviso para mostrar el sweet alert con el parametro php

Comment: no, el codigo sin embargo no me sirvio alvaro.
me redirige luego de presionar el ok pero me lleva a una pagina indefinida... por que podria pasar eso?

Comment: pero si el codigo sin el sweet alert me dirige a la pagina que quiero, como puede el sweet alert cambiar ese parametro php sino esta tocando variables? 
almenos podria ser que no este bien el  window.location.href = e.target.href?

Comment: Podrías crear otra pregunta, o editar esta y mostrar el código que estás utilizando.

Comment: ya la edite @Shaz

Comment: El problema es que tenías elementos hijos en el `<a>`, por lo cual los elementos que activan el evento click son estos, ya modifiqué mi código para que revise si tienen el enlace o no, y de no tenerlo, busquen hasta llegar a `<a>`

Comment: DIABLOS!!! yo no me iba a dar cuenta de eso nunca !

Comment: es precisamente esa la correxion que necesitaba @Shaz perdona soy muy noob te agradezco enormemente tu tiempo (Y)

Comment: no habia visto la otra opcion (y) listo bro , u rock