# sweetAlert 2 con envio de parametro

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert

Buenas tengo esta funcion de confirmación para eliminar un registro como puedo hacerlo para al momento de confirmar enviar un parametro del form hacia otro archivo php para proceder a elimninar el registro obviamente con ajax.
Saludos

```
 function mensajeEliminar() {
swal({
    title: "¿Esta Seguro ?",
   text: "¿Desea eliminar este usuario?",
   icon: "warning",
    dangerMode : true,
    buttons : ["Cancelar","Aceptar"]
}).then((confirmacion)=>{
    if(confirmacion)
        swal("Exito","Has eliminado el registro","success");
    else
        ;
});
```

}

Comment: Buenas saludos, no entiendo tu duda, la web de la librería explica como hacer esa parte. Si muestras un código ejemplo de lo que intentas podemos ayudarme mejor. Saludos

Comment: Cuando lo intentas si te abre el alert?

Comment: si si me lo muestra habia tenido problemas con la nueva versión ahora lo que quiero es que al confirmar se mande un parametro de un form a otra pagina para que proceda a eliminarel usuario

Comment: Tengo este ejemplo de como usarlo. (https://codepen.io/thavoo/pen/jQqwgE)

Comment: Ahora si quieres enviar parametros para el server ya debes utilizar axios, ajax o fetch. Pero ya no es el tema principal de la duda amigo.

Comment: si cambiare la pregunta porque ya solucione lo del sweet alert gracias  :D

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146803/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-cuadro-de-dialogo-alert-para-que-de-acuerdo-a-mi-confirmaci%C3%B3n-e
puedes ver una forma como yo lo hago...

Comment: si pero para pasar un parametro por ajax por ejemplo tomar el valor de una caja de texto y enviarlo y unirlo al mensaje de confirmar eliminacion de sweetalert